# Launchd - Standard output is not being logged

Tags: c, macos, stdout, launchd

Consider the situation bellow:

**main.c**

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    fprintf(stdout, "STDOUT: I belong to stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "STDERR: I belong to stderr\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**test.launchd.plist**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test.launchd.plist</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/the/compiled/binary</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/err</string>
    <key>StandardInPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/in</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/out</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/tmp</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I get `STDERR: I belong to stderr` in the **/tmp/err** file, but no `STDOUT: I belong to stdout` in the **/tmp/out** file. Is this a known error or have I done something wrong?

I'm running macOS 10.14.4 beta 3.

Comment: ???you belong to some files???  not likely.  When you run the program, you can 'redirect' the `stderr` and `stdout` to different files.   What is the 'xml' file expected to do?

Comment: @user3629249, I can do that if I want. But that's not the point. According to the **launchd** documentation, `StandardOutPath` _should_ redirect standard output to the given file. The file (i.e. **/tmp/out**) is created but there's nothing inside it.

Comment: @user3629249, I suppose you know that this is not a mere **xml** file, by the way. It's a launch daemon. I mentioned using launchd.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the logging [INFO behavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code) in macOS, stdout is persisted to disk only when collected with the log tool (out of speculating). However, if you flush stdout, you'll see the content you want in `/tmp/out`.